# How does pandas rolling_mean() work?

Tags: python, pandas, moving-average

I need to use a moving average to smooth my data, so I have written a function using convolution. But the results are a left shift compared to my raw data. So I have used the built-in `rolling_mean()` from pandas and it works just fine. The problem is I don't want to use pandas and I'm trying to rewrite this function, but the source code does not explain how it works (or maybe it just me).

My original function was

```
def moving_average(data, window):
    return np.convolve(data, np.ones(window)/window, mode='valid')
```

Source code of pandas `rolling_mean()` is:

```
def f(arg, window, min_periods=None, freq=None, center=False, how=how,
      **kwargs):
    def call_cython(arg, window, minp, args=(), kwargs={}, **kwds):
        minp = check_minp(minp, window)
        return func(arg, window, minp, **kwds)
    return _rolling_moment(arg, window, call_cython, min_periods, freq=freq,
                           center=center, how=how, **kwargs)
```

The key is the argument "center", but I don't know how its works.[image: Picture what I mean]
Blue is raw data, green is my attempt, and red (correct) version is from pandas.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't one correct way to smooth data, and even if you're using the mean there's still a lot of variation.  Shifting is a very common result from simple rolling means though.

The bit of code you posted from `pandas.rolling_mean` doesn't show the operation; you can see where it specifies, for example, `how=how` that it's passing a parameter that isn't included in your snippet to determine what method it uses.  It also references `cython` so I assume the guts of the command are written in C, not in Python (common because it's a lot faster).

I didn't go hunting for the underlying code because `rolling_mean` doesn't have much documentation *and* is deprecated to boot.  Instead take a look at [rolling](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) from the latest version of Pandas, and it tells you what types of smoothers it can do.  You might try passing those parameters into the `rolling` function and seeing which one does what you want; then you can look up the math behind it from a source of your choice to reproduce elsewhere.

I don't know the original poster's level of experience, but for anyone reading this who might not be well versed in signal processing or data smoothing, separating noise from trends is a huge area of research.  Be very careful when you do it though, because the result is very sensitive to the method.  For a few others, in addition to all the rolling functions Pandas offers, take a look at Holt-Winters, Baxter-King or Hodrick-Prescott.  They all approach the problem differently, with very different results, strengths and weaknesses.